# Unittest polymer.dart with karma

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

The problem is polymer is not loading. Karma has filters for the files it loads, I'm trying load and initialize polymer to be able to test polymer elements with no success (outside the test environment the code works fine).

Debugging the code in the browser I don't see the polymer.html loaded, and besides the custom element is in the page, they do not have the properties and behavior, and don't have the shadow dom.

What I try to do:

karma.conf.js

```js
    /**
     * Compile HTML into JS so that they can be used as templates
     */
    preprocessors: {
        'packages/**/*.html': 'html2js'
    },
    basePath: '.',
    frameworks: ['dart-unittest'],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    // all tests must be 'included', but all other libraries must be 'served' and
    // optionally 'watched' only.
    files: [
        'test/*.dart',
        {pattern: '**/*.dart', watched: true, included: false, served: true},
        'packages/browser/dart.js',
        {pattern: 'scripts/**/*.js', included: false},
        {pattern: '**/*.html', included: false, served: true},
        'packages/polymer/polymer.html'
    ],

    autoWatch: true,

    // If browser does not capture in given timeout [ms], kill it
    captureTimeout: 5000,

    plugins: [
        'karma-dart'
    ]
```

test_index.html

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Run Unit Tests</title>
    <link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html" />
    <link rel="import" href="packages/vader/components/window.html" />
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="packages/unittest/test_controller.js"></script>

<script type="application/dart;component=1" src="test_vader_browser.dart"></script>
<script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

test_vader_browser.dart

```dart
import 'package:scheduled_test/scheduled_test.dart';
import 'vader/_vader.dart' as vader;
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
@initMethod
main() {
  setUp((){
    schedule(() => Polymer.onReady);
  });
  groupSep = ' - ';
  vader.runAllTests();
}
```